# Matlab vs Octave Compatibility - computer vision differences?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, octave, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to get this Matlab example from the MathWorks site to work with Octave 4.0.0:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html

I made a GitHub repository for what I have so far, which mostly a re-formatted version of the MathWorks link above:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/Matlab_Octave_Multiple_Object_Tracking

The only changes I have made so far are:

-Made a separate main.m file to run multiObjectTracking.m

-Since I don't have the 'atrium.avi' file used by MathWorks, I changed the VideoFileReader line in the code to use '768x576.avi', which is included with OpenCV ('768x576.avi' is also uploaded to the GitHub repo linked above)

-Minor spacing and comment changes

-added "pkg load image;" at the beginning of main.m and multiObjectTracking.m, in the few test Octave computer vision programs I did this seemed to be necessary, otherwise I would get an error to the effect of "library image has been installed but not loaded"

Currently when I run the program I get the following error:

```
error: 'vision' undefined near line 38 column 18
error: called from
    multiObjectTracking>setupSystemObjects at line 38 column 16
    multiObjectTracking at line 14 column 7
    main at line 14 column 1
```

In other words in the function:

```
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  function obj = setupSystemObjects()
    % initialize Video I/O, create objects for reading a video from a file, drawing the tracked objects in each frame, and playing the video

    obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader('768x576.avi');           % create a video file reader

    obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [20, 400, 700, 400]);      % create two video players, one to display the video,
    obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [740, 400, 700, 400]);      % and one to display the foreground mask

    % Create System objects for foreground detection and blob analysis

    % The foreground detector is used to segment moving objects from the background. It outputs a binary mask, where the pixel value
    % of 1 corresponds to the foreground and the value of 0 corresponds to the background

    obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, 'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);

    % Connected groups of foreground pixels are likely to correspond to moving objects.  The blob analysis System object is used to find such groups
    % (called 'blobs' or 'connected components'), and compute their characteristics, such as area, centroid, and the bounding box.

    obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, 'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, 'MinimumBlobArea', 400);
  end
```

The 'vision' object is not recognized.

It is my understanding that 'vision' is part of the Matlab Toolbox, but I am unable to confirm this since I don't have access to Matlab.

So here are my questions so far:

-Is there an Octave equivalent of the 'vision' object?

-What other differences should I be aware of to get this Matlab program running under Octave ??

I have been attempting to use the following site:

http://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/

but have not been very successful so far getting these examples working or as a guide to the Matlab to Octave translation I'm attempting.

Any assistance from Octave experts or those who have gotten computer vision working in both Matlab and Octave would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are Matlab functions from the [Computer Vision System Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/video-loading-saving-and-display.html).

General rule is, Octave comes short in matching Matlab toolboxes and when it has something, you need to install the [Octave packages separately](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB#GNU_Octave_Control_Package).

The link to the site you supplied does not seem to provide support for `vision` object functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So additional questions I would have now are:

-Do you think it's a hopeless task to translate the above Matlab program into Octave?

-Looking at the "image" package for Octave, it would seem that the functionality is similar to "vision" in Matlab, are they pretty close or completely different?

(continued on next post, I'm running out of characters .  .  .)

Comment: -I'm very fluent in OpenCV C++ and Visual Basic (using Emgu CV as a wrapper for OpenCV).  Would it be better to read the Matlab example in one screen and translate it into OpenCV C++/VB on my other screen, even though I won't be able to run the Matlab example?  Or would you suggest I keep trying to translate the Matlab example into a working Octave example first?

At this point my inclination is to skip Octave and translate directly into C++ or VB as I have very little Octave experience.

(continued on next post again, I'm running out of characters again . . .)

Comment: Thanks again for the info so far, I don't expect anybody to translate the Matlab program into Octave line by line for me, of course that's up to me to do, but if you could make some suggestions to provide further direction that would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have enough expertise to help you. My experience with Octave is limited to the core set of functions. The also have the video package that might be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I appreciate your help so far.  Can anybody else out there offer any further advisement before I dive into translating the Matlab program to C++ or VB ??